# Android Studio SDK Missing

Tags: android, sdk, android-2.2-froyo, android-studio

I installed **Android Studio** , and edited all **Configurations** and all what has been **written** on blogs , but But still show the **same message** :

> Your Android SDK is out of date or is missing templates. Please ensure you are using SDK version 22 or later.

What do I will do now ?!!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open your SDK manager from Eclipse and update you Android SDK Tools from 21.1 to 22.That will solve your problem.